# Prisma resolver query && GraphQL Shield

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma

I am experimenting Prisma GraphQL with GraphQL Shield, btw awesome stuff!

Alas I am trying to create a login system using JWT, but I am finding a bottleneck.

This will **NOT** work

```js
Mutation: {
    login: (_, data: UserWhereUniqueInput, ctx) => {
      return ctx.db
        .user({ email: ctx.request.body.variables.email, password: ctx.request.body.variables.password })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => err)
    },

  ...
}
```

But this **DOES**

If I change to password, it will work to. (so only one condition on the where)

```js
Mutation: {
    login: (_, data: UserWhereUniqueInput, ctx) => {
      return ctx.db
        .user({ email: ctx.request.body.variables.email })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => err)
    },

  ...
}
```

why is that?

Another thing is:

if I add query to the `ctx.db` like so:

```js
Mutation: {
    login: (_, data: UserWhereUniqueInput, ctx) => {
      return ctx.db.query
        .user({ email: ctx.request.body.variables.email })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => err)
    },

  ...
}
```

I get

> Error: Not Authorised!

Even though I am using the allow on graphQL shield

```js
Mutation: {
  login: allow,
},
Query: {
  user: allow,
}
```

Any Ideas? :/

If someone with better knowledge than me could point me to the right direction I would be very grateful